# log4j2 parameter substitution does not invoke toString() method

Tags: java, parameters, log4j2, substitution

```
Class T {
   public String toString() {
       return "Instance of T";
   }
}

Class T2 extends Date {
   public String toString() {
       return "Instance of T2";
   }
}

//log4j2 calls
log.info("T : {}",  new T());
log.info("T2: {}",  new T2());
```

```
// log4j output
 T : instance of T
 T2: 2019-12-04T13:48:51.012-0500
```

In the above example why log4j2 doesn't call toString() method of Class T2?

Comment: Tried with log4J, could not reproduce the issue. Do you mind sharing the Log4J implementation code?

Comment: I would guess that log4j2 is likely checking whether the instance of the object parameter is a `Date` and then treating it as a `Date` rather than a general `Object`